# Show or hide fields in view based on a user relationship

Tags: views, entities, users

I have a table on my site made with views. I have the [User Relationships](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_relationships) module installed so users can connect with each other.
I want most of the fields to be visible for all users but there is one field that must only be showed if the author of the content and the logged in user have a relation with each other.

Is this even possible? I have tried different settings.
It is possible with a filter criteria to hide the complete node if the users aren't related. But that is not what I want. It is just one field of that node type that must be hidden if the users aren't related.